# Merge Data from two hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I want to merge the following two arrays of hashes (`arr1` and `arr2`). What is the best way to do this?

The aggregation is to be done on the value of the key `:_id`.

```
arr1 = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 3
    },
    "enroll_count": 2267
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 2
    },
    "enroll_count": 1829
  }
]

arr2 = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 3
    },
    "other_count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 2
    },
    "other_count": 3
  }
]
```

Desired Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 3
    },
    "enrolled_count": 2267,
    "other_count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": 2
    },
    "enrolled_count": 1829
    "other_count": 3
  }
]
```

I tried using `Hash#merge` but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
(arr1+arr2).each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h.update(g[:_id]=>g) {|_,o,n| o.merge(n)}}.values
  #=> [{:_id=>{:year=>2017, :month=>3}, :enroll_count=>2267, :other_count=>2},
  #    {:_id=>{:year=>2017, :month=>2}, :enroll_count=>1829, :other_count=>3}]
```

Note that before `.values` is executed we have

```
(arr1+arr2).each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h.update(g[:_id]=>g) {|_,o,n| o.merge(n)}}
  #=> {{:year=>2017, :month=>3}=>{:_id=>{:year=>2017, :month=>3},
  #                               :enroll_count=>2267,
  #                               :other_count=>2
  #                              },
  #    {:year=>2017, :month=>2}=>{:_id=>{:year=>2017, :month=>2},
  #                               :enroll_count=>1829,
  #                               :other_count=>3
  #                              }
  #   }
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (`{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }`) to determine the values of keys (`:_id`) that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for an explanation of the values of the three block variables in that value-resolution block.

This method does not require the hashes that are to be combined to have the same indices in their respective arrays.